# Get Rigidbody2D collision velocity without the sliding factor

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a flying car that I want to lose some HP when colliding with objects.

I connected car's RigidBody2D to this function to do that

```
func _on_Car_body_entered(body):
    var force = linear_velocity.length()
    var dmg = pow(force / 100, 2) - 0.25
    if dmg <= 0: return
    Health = Health - dmg
```

Now, since I don't have to be precise I'm just using current velocity as the force, though this is up for change.

After getting my 'force of impact', I put it into damage calculating formula and if damage is above 0, decrease HP by damage.

This works fine in most cases

**BUT**

I noticed that if car's going fast horizontally and just barely touch the ground (that's perfectly horizontal), car gets hit with a lot of damage, because I'm using the length of the velocity vector.

Ofcourse, this case can be managed by using just the Y component of the velocity vector, but then it removes any horizontal collisions, and vice versa, and it also leads me on to the path of programming vertical and horizontal collisions, and ofcourse those are not the only 2 directions of colisions I need.

Is there a way to remove the sliding factor from this equation?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for my problem [here](https://godotengine.org/qa/13155/get-collision-force)

**This gives me a predictable force range to work with.**

I copied all code for 2D collision, just added damage calculation

Range of forces my objects produce is  <3000 for small collisions like scratches and bumps, ~10k for beginner friendly damage, and 20k+ for when I really slam the gas pedal, so I just convert that force to damage that I want.

Best part is that I don't have to use the `body_entered` from `RigidBody2D`, because now all my cars have this calculation in them, so when 2 of them collide they both get damaged.

```
extends RigidBody2D

var collision_force : Vector2 = Vector2.ZERO
var previous_linear_velocity : Vector2 = Vector2.ZERO

func _integrate_forces(state : Physics2DDirectBodyState)->void:
    collision_force = Vector2.ZERO

    if state.get_contact_count() > 0:
        var dv : Vector2 = state.linear_velocity - previous_linear_velocity
        collision_force = dv / (state.inverse_mass * state.step)

    var dmg = collision_force.length() / 2000 - 2
    if dmg > 0:
        set_hp(Health - dmg)
        emit_signal("Damaged")


    previous_linear_velocity = state.linear_velocity
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

**RUBBER DUCK HERE**

In script for car I added a new variable `var last_linear_velocity = Vector2()`

Then stored the last velocity in `_process`

```
func _process(delta):
    last_linear_velocity = linear_velocity
```

Not in `_integrate_forces` because if I put it there then the new and last velocities are the same.

And just changed how force is calculated in the function mentioned above, so it looks like this

```
func _on_Car_body_entered(body):
    var force = last_linear_velocity.length() - linear_velocity.length()
    var dmg = pow(force / 100, 2) - 0.25
    if dmg <= 0: return
    Health = Health - dmg
```

Now I get a nice predicable range of values and can transform that to damage.

**NOTE**

I noticed that sometimes when collision occures the difference between the last and current velocity lengths is negative, as in - car is accelerating.

Anyway, this works for me for now.

If you find a better solutions do post it, as I couldn't find a solution to this problem online elswhere.

Comment: This is the right idea. Force is mass times acceleration. And acceleration is a change in velocity. I would divide by the physics delta, so you have acceleration instead of a delta velocity. You can disregard the sign. And you may scale it by a "mass" factor you can tweak… Anyway, damage is not force, you can have a minimum threshold for a force to cause damage, and - as you do - have a force to damage function. I would base it on effort-deformation, but you do you. It is not clear what health means in physics terms anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can **get the sine of the angle between your velocity and the collision normal, and then take the absolute of that**.

```
# 0 When sliding along the wall. 1 when hitting the wall head on
var slide_factor = abs(cos(vel_last_frame.angle_to(collision_normal)))
```

This will give you a value from 0 to 1. When you are just sliding along the wall, this value will be 0, and when you hit the wall straight on, it will be 1.

I am using the velocity from the last frame here so that it gets the velocity just before the collision. I get it by setting `vel_last_frame` to `linear_velocity` inside the `_physics_process` function.

You can only get the collision normal inside the `_integrate_forces` function using [PhysicsDirectBodyState.get_local_contact_normal()](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_physicsdirectbodystate.html#class-physicsdirectbodystate-method-get-contact-local-normal), so you need to make a variable that can be accessed in this function and the `_on_Car_body_entered` function. Note that you need to set `contact_monitor` to **true** and `contacts_reported` to **at least 1** for this function to work.

```
var collision_normal

func _integrate_forces(state):
    # Check if there is a collision
    if state.get_contact_count():
        # contact_monitor must be true and contacts_reported must be at least 1 for this to work
        collision_normal = state.get_contact_local_normal(0)
```

Now in the `_on_Car_body_entered_function`, you can multiply `dmg` by `sliding_factor` to scale it less depending on how much you are sliding against the wall.

```
func _on_Car_body_entered(body):
    var force = linear_velocity.length()
    # 0 When sliding along the wall. 1 when hitting the wall head on
    var slide_factor = abs(cos(vel_last_frame.angle_to(collision_normal)))
    var dmg = pow(force / 100, 2) - 0.25
    # Reduce dmg depending on how much you are sliding against the wall
    dmg *= slide_factor
    
    if dmg <= 0: return
    Health = Health - dmg
```